# MSbuild Update all assembly file in a solution with svn build revision

Tags: visual-studio, svn, msbuild, version

Is there a way using msbuild community task, to update all the assemblyInfo.cs in a solution with the SVN build number. There is a a lot of solution out there using FileUpdate but the source is one file and not all the files.

```
 <FileUpdate Files="version.txt"
  Regex="(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)"
  ReplacementText="$1.$2.$3.123" />
```

I want dynamically to go through all the projects and change it version without knowing the projects file name in the solution

Comment: I'd add a seperate project which all others depend on, so it will always be built first, and which recursively lists all AssemblyInfo.cs files under the solution directory for example. Then change the version in each file - ideally only when it really changed though to avoid rebuilds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could look for all assemblyinfo.cs files by using wildcards. For example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyInfoFiles Include="..\**\AssemblyInfo.cs"/>
 </ItemGroup>
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
<FileUpdate Files="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)"
  Regex="(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)"
  ReplacementText="$1.$2.$3.123" />
</Target>
```

Then as stijn said that, you can add a project which all others depend on if you want update all assemblyinfo.cs files before build.

If you want to update all asseblyinfo.cs files after build, you need to add other projects' reference to this project.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about how to add other projects reference and keep it fully dynamic

Comment: You can add other projects' reference manually (right click reference=>Add reference) or edit project file directly (add ProjectReference to ItemGroup)